# Open a paragraph programmatically

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I have a paragraph `contact`  nested inside another paragraph `occurrence`.

In the widget settings the paragraph `contact` is defined to be collapsed by default (`edit_mode` = `closed`).

I want the `contact` paragraph only to be open  when creating the content and only on the first `occurrence`.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please modify the question to explain the precise meaning of "open" and "closed" in this context?

Comment: Do you just need to define a default paragraph bundle on the form display settings for the field?

Comment: @cilefen with close I mean collapsed an open, the contrary uncollapsed. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I wanted to to by letting the contact field open by default (edit_mode = open) and then in an `hook_form_node_form_alter` remove the contact form with this code

```
// Collapse contact field except for the first occurence.
foreach ($form['field_occurence']['widget'] as $delta => $field) {
  if (is_int($delta) && $delta != 0 && isset($field['subform']['field_contact']['widget']['0']['subform']['#type'])) {
    unset($form['field_occurence']['widget'][$delta]['subform']['field_contact']['widget']['0']);
  }
}
```

I guess there is a cleaner way but form the moment that does the trick.